# How do I ignore the field which is not populated when dumping a struct?

Tags: gdb

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Foo {
   char *name,
   int priority
};
```

I have a gdb function to printout the content of the struct:

```
define p_Foo
   printf "Foo(%lx:\n", $arg0
   set $f = (struct Foo*)$arg0
   printf "name = %s\n", $f.name
   printf "priority = $d\n", $f.priority
end
```

The problem is, when the name field is not populated, the above function stops running without printing priority field:

```
(gdb) p_Foo 0x56000b8bb888
Foo(56000b8bb888):
name =Cannot access memory at address 0x400000002
```

You can see priority is not print out. I will need to issue another command to see both fields in this case:

```
(gdb)p *$f
$5 = {
  name = 0x400000002 <Address 0x400000002 out of bounds>,
  priority = 170139020,
}
```

My question is, how should I write that GDB function p_Foo so that it can print all the fields even when some of them are wild pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> how should I write that GDB function p_Foo so that it can print all the fields even when some of them are wild pointers.

You can implement a Python pretty-printer, as documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html).

In addition to being able to catch exceptions, another advantage is that you would be able to use `print *(struct Foo*)0x56000b8bb888` (or `p *(strcut Foo*)0x56000b8bb888`) instead of `p_Foo 0x56000b8bb888`.